# Mixed content error while serving wordpress from another instance

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to serve a WordPress application from `https://example.com/blog`. The issue is that `https://example.com` is hosted on another instance and I am redirecting `/blog` to other instance. The server I am using is Nginx. This is my Nginx configuration.

```
server {
 server_name example.com;

  location / {
   try_files $uri $uri /index.html;
  }

  location ^~ /blog {
   proxy_pass http://<IP>/blog;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

   allow <IP>;
 }
}
```

As the `/blog` is running on other instance it is giving me Mixed-content errors because the proxy is passed to `http:IP` and it is loaded over `https`. Please help me solveing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTPS']` needs to be set to `on` in case you're accessing it through proxy_pass and deliver it via HTTPS. Otherwise, WordPress knows it's forwarded, but cannot check whether it's delivered via HTTP or HTTPS to the outside. Add these lines to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

Please note that if there are multiple proxies and one of those doesn't serve HTTPS, you have to make that condition based on what `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` actually contains. For now, we're only checking if it's non-empty and by that we assume it's supposed to be HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all mixed-content errors are gone but now it is giving ```net:: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR```. Because it is taking this path : ```https://<IP>/blog/wp-content/..```